# C# Webforms - Add <strong> around text portion if a condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am working on adding simple blogging functionality to a C# Webforms (Bootstrap) site and am trying to create a site archive in a right-hand column. The archive displays the list of past 6 months, whether or not any articles were published in that month. Each month (item in list) has a badge attached to it with the number of posts published in that month displayed in it. If there are no posts, the badge collapses (Bootstrap). In addition, the currently selected month is bolded, which is where my problem lies.

I want to iterate over the past 6 months in an orderly fashion, calculating the amount of articles in the given month and whether or not it is the selected month.

Here is what the archive currently looks like (testing colours :) ):

[image: Blog Archive]

As you can see, September has been highlighted because it was the month selected by the URL (`...BlogArchive?year=2015&month=September`). Currently, this is my code for highlighting the current month:

```
<div class="list-group blog-archive">
    <% DateTime monthCounter = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            monthCounter = monthCounter.AddMonths(1);

            //Get the number of posts in the current month list-item
            string numberOfPostsInMonth = GetNumberOfPostsInMonth(monthCounter.ToString("MMMM"), monthCounter.ToString("yyyy"));
            string archiveURL = "";

            if (numberOfPostsInMonth != "")
            {
                //Get the URL to pass to the Blog Archive link 'href'
                archiveURL = "BlogArchive?year=" + monthCounter.ToString("yyyy") + "&month=" + monthCounter.ToString("MMMM");
            }
            else
            {
                archiveURL = "BlogArchive";
            }

            if (monthCounter.ToString("yyyy") == SelectedYear && monthCounter.ToString("MMMM") == SelectedMonth)
            {
                %>
                <a href="<%=archiveURL %>" class="list-group-item"><strong><%=monthCounter.ToString("MMMM yyyy") %></strong>
                    <span class="badge"><%=numberOfPostsInMonth %></span>
                </a>
                <%
            }
            else
            {
                %>
                <a href="<%=archiveURL %>" class="list-group-item"><%=monthCounter.ToString("MMMM yyyy") %>
                    <span class="badge"><%=numberOfPostsInMonth %></span>
                </a>
                <%
            }                       
    } %>
</div>
```

This is less than ideal however, as I have the same `<a>` tag statement repeated twice -- the only difference is that the one has a `<strong>` tag (and closing tag) applied and the other does not. Also, I'm going to add functionality so that all months without posts will not contain links (as there is nothing to see -> ie. June - August). Currently, this will involve adding the same `if` statement to both `<a>` statements above, which again seems like pointless duplication, especially if I need to change it in the future.

Is there a way to simplify the above statement so that I'm not repeating the same `<a>` statement? I'm trying to think of a way to only apply the `<strong>` tag if the list month is equal to the selected month, but don't know of a way to fit in the closing tag (`</strong>`), as there is text in between that needs to be there regardless of the results of the `if` statement (ie, the badge and post count).

Thanks!

---

### Update

I have now received a reply stating that I need to output a link only when there are blog posts for a month (and just text otherwise). This is to prevent the user from accessing an empty page.

I managed to solve it this way:

```
<div class="list-group blog-archive">
    <% DateTime monthCounter = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            monthCounter = monthCounter.AddMonths(1);

            string monthHTML = "";
            string monthText = monthCounter.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
            string monthURL = "";
            string badgeHTML = "";
            string numberOfPostsInMonth = GetNumberOfPostsInMonth(monthCounter.ToString("MMMM"), monthCounter.ToString("yyyy"));

            //Bold the selected month list-item
            if (monthCounter.ToString("yyyy") == SelectedYear && monthCounter.ToString("MMMM") == SelectedMonth)
            {
                monthText = "<strong>" + monthText + "</strong>";
            }

            //If there are posts in the month, print the month as a link.
            //  Otherwise, if there are no posts in the month, print the month as a '<span>' rather than a link
            if (numberOfPostsInMonth != "")
            {
                monthURL = "BlogArchive?year=" + monthCounter.ToString("yyyy") + "&month=" + monthCounter.ToString("MMMM");
                badgeHTML = "<span class=\"badge\">" + numberOfPostsInMonth + "</span>";

                monthHTML = "<a href=\"" + monthURL + "\" class=\"list-group-item\">" + monthText + badgeHTML + "</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                monthHTML = "<span class=\"list-group-item\">" + monthText + badgeHTML + "</span>";
            }

            //Write the month list item to the page
            Response.Write(monthHTML);
        }
    %>
</div>
```

At this point I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this? Especially the Response.Write(), is that actually the best way to output to the page from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of outputting the text directly and surrounding it with a `strong` tag, you could change your code to a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) and by that separate the layout from the logic. Your Repeater would look similar to this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMonths" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="list-group blog-archive">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView runat="server" ActiveViewIndex='<%# Eval("ViewIndex") %>'>
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ArchiveUrl") %>'
                      CssClass="list-group-item">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MonthName") %>' 
                          CssClass='<%# Eval("MonthClass") %>' />
                    <span class="badge"><%# Eval("NumberOfPosts") %></span>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MonthName") %>'
                    CssClass='<%# Eval("MonthClass") %>' />
                <span class="badge"><%# Eval("NumberOfPosts") %></span>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Please notice that a MultiView is used to render the link only if the URL is set. Also, a label is used to create a span with a CssClass so that you can set the style.

To provide the data, you'd need a class similar to this one:

```
public class MonthSummary
{
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get { return Month.ToString("MMMM"); } }
    public string MonthClass { get; set; }
    public string ArchiveUrl { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPosts { get; set; }
    public int ViewIndex { get; set; }
}
```

When loading the page, you'd assemble the month data, e.g. in PageLoad:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var lst = new List<MonthSummary>();
        for (var m = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-5); m <= DateTime.Today; m = m.AddMonths(1))
        {
            var summary = new MonthSummary();
            summary.Month = m;
            if (int.Parse(SelectedYear) == m.Year && int.Parse(SelectedMonth) == m.Month)
                summary.MonthClass = "HighlightedMonth";
            else
                summary.MonthClass = string.Empty;
            summary.NumberOfPosts = 0; // get the number of posts in an appropriate way
            if (summary.NumberOfPosts > 0)
            {
                summary.ArchiveUrl = "~/BlogArchive?year=" + m.Year.ToString() + "&month=" + m.Month.ToString();
                summary.ViewIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                summary.ArchiveUrl = string.Empty;
                summary.ViewIndex = 1;
            }
            lst.Add(summary);
        }
        rptMonths.DataSource = lst;
        rptMonths.DataBind();
    }

}
```

When assembling the data, change the ViewIndex for months that do not have posts. The second view does not contain the Hyperlink control and therefore does not render a `a` tag.

Finally, you'd need to define the class in CSS to format the text in bold.

Comment: That looks interesting! However, I have just received confirmation that if there are no posts in a month the user should not be able to access that month. Therefore, I need to output `<span>` instead of `<a>` if there are no posts for the month (otherwise the user would be taken to an empty page). Thanks anyway! I'll definitely remember this for future use!

Comment: @KendallRoth I've updated my answer so that you can also leave the URL blank if there are no posts in a month. This looks like a big change for sure, but it will pay off.

Comment: Thanks. That would work, but wouldn't this still allow the user to click on a link, or at least think it was a link (and be frustrated when clicking does nothing)? Also, I don't think that leaving an empty `href=""` is going to pass some of the checks that we have in place...the standards are rather strict.

Comment: @KendallRoth in a small test my browser did not show a link if the href was not just empty but omitted. Of course, if your checks are so strict, you will need some if-statements.

Comment: @KendallRoth I've added a MultiView to the ItemTemplate. The Hyperlink is only used when there is a ArchiveUrl.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I believe this is what I'm looking for. I've never run into WebForms before as we normally run with MVC, but this project was different. Thanks for the intro to the "codeBehind"!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a class witch set

```
font-weight: bold;
```

On base of your condition add the class or dont add the class

Youre code will looks like something like this:

```
string stylingclass = String.Empty;
if(condition) {stylingclass = "YourCssClassHere";}

....
<a href="<%=archiveURL %>>" class="list-group-item <%=stylingclass%>"><%=monthCounter.ToString("MMMM yyyy") %>
....
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this at one point but discarded it due to the fact that I eventually want months without any posts to be displayed as text only, and not a link. However, I didn't really think about it too much, and this prompted me to think about it again. I'll try it and let you know if it works!

Comment: I just received a reply to a question I had asked the client, and found out that I now need to use an `<a>` tag when there are posts in a month and a `<span>` when there are no posts (this prevents the user from accessing an empty page). Thanks anyway!